# Needed: mysql current timestamp on update also if UPDATE does not change values in table

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a database with 3 columns:

ID / Price / last_updated

The column "last_updated" has ..

- as **type**: timestamp
- as **Standard**: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- as **Attribute**: CURRENT TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE
- as **Extra** : CURRENT TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE

when I run a mysql_query(UPDATE...) to change the prices, some prices do not change. In those cases, however, the last_updated value remains the same than before (which in this case is: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as the records have not been changed).

So I guess, UPDATE only "updates" if the new value is different from the current one in place.

How can I get the current timestamp put into the table, even if the value is not changed after performing a mysql_query(UPDATE...) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query, just always update the `last_updated` field using `NOW()`.  Like this:

```
UPDATE table SET price = ?, last_updated = NOW() WHERE id = ??
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this :

```
ALTER TABLE myTable 
MODIFY last_updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

For a one time fix, on the existing table :

```
update myTable set last_updated=now() where last_updated='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: This will only set the value of the last_updated to current_timestamp only when a new row is created, If you want this to change on every update, you can use a trigger on this table